# KMC doesn't load after kaltura installation on centos

Tags: centos, kaltura

I installed kaltura CE5 on centos 6.4 64 bit version. I followed instructions from http://www.sparksupport.com/blog/how-to-install-kaltura-in-centos. The installation is successfull but I am not able to launch KMC. The KAC works fine. I tried logging in from KAC too. I have tried it on 32 bit too. Pls advise.
thanks!
ib

Answer (score 1):

Kaltura CE5 is an outdated system.
You should install the new Kaltura CE9X 
Use CentOS 6.5 64 bit (32 bit systems are not supported) and follow this tutorial (for stand alone system):
https://github.com/kaltura/platform-install-packages/blob/master/doc/install-kaltura-redhat-based.md

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't support mysql 5.5 either.

Answer (score 0):

if the installation is ok with the command localhost.localdomain/start the starting page will open. (replace with the localhost and localdomain you have chosen like kaltura.yourdomain.com)

To open the kmc use the url localhost.localdomain/kmc on the web browser.